Show that a given procedure generates all rationals greater than 1
Question without Context
Let be given a sequence of natural numbers $(A_1,A_2,...)$, such that $A_i\ge A_{i-1}+1$, and consider the set generated by dividing $(1,...,A_1)$ by $1$, $(A_1,...,A_2)$ by $2$ and so on. Specifically,
$${\cal A}=(p/q\in\mathbb{Q})(\exists i\in\mathbb{N})(\exists n\in[A_{i-1},A_{i}]\cap\mathbb{N})(p/q=n/i)$$
Under what sufficient conditions on the sequence $A_i$ is it true that $\mathbb{Q}\cap[1,\infty]={\cal A}$?
Example of a sequence for which the above holds
A one-parameter family (denote the parameter as $\lambda$) of sequences $A_i$ for which (it should be true that*) $\mathbb{Q}\cap[1,\infty]={\cal A}$ can be defined as follows. Pick any $\lambda\in\mathbb{Q}\cap[1,\infty]$ and start by defining $B_i$ as
$$B_i=\underset{k\in\mathbb{N}}{\rm argmin}\Bigg(\frac{B_0+...+B_{i-1}+1+k}{\lambda}>i+1\Bigg)$$
with $B_0=\underset{k\in\mathbb{N}}{\rm argmin}(k+1>\lambda)$. Then let $$A_i=B_0+...+B_{i-1}+1$$
Context
I am trying to write a proof for the fact that starting in the pre-image of a torus and going in a straight line, if the slope of said line is rational, then we will eventually arrive back where we started so that we generate a torus knot. I am not interested in finding a proof (there are many available), but rather in proving a specific step in the one I have written.
*(See Context) The family of sequences mentioned above should satisfy $\mathbb{Q}\cap[1,\infty]={\cal A}$ on the condition that there is no error until they appear in the torus-knot proof I have written.

Do you mean to include both $\frac{A_i}i$ and $\frac{A_i}{i+1}$? Or should $[A_{i-1},A_i]$ be $(A_{i-1},A_i]$?

Two obviously necessary conditions are $\liminf \frac{A_i}i = 1$ and $\limsup \frac{A_i}i = \infty$. Do you know of any specific example of a sequence $(A_i)$ for which the conclusion is true?

@GregMartin Thank you for your comments. First of all $[A_i,A_{i+1}]$ was not a typo, I do indeed include both. I have added a family of such sequences for which the above should hold. This family should be able to be expressed much more simply.
